# Extract unique parts of a string enclosed by brackets in order

Tags: python

I want to extract data contained within brackets and print it in another text file.

my text file is

> RAH71880.1 phenol monooxygenase [Aspergillus aculeatinus CBS 121060]
>   PVV21043.1 phenol 2-monooxygenase [gamma proteobacterium symbiont of
>   Ctena orbiculata] PVV21041.1 phenol hydroxylase [gamma proteobacterium
>   symbiont of Ctena orbiculata] PYH66749.1 phenol monooxygenase
>   [Aspergillus vadensis CBS 113365] PYH31415.1 phenol monooxygenase
>   [Aspergillus neoniger CBS 115656] PUB86175.1 phenol 2-monooxygenase
>   [gamma proteobacterium symbiont of Ctena orbiculata] PUB86141.1 phenol
>   2-monooxygenase [gamma proteobacterium symbiont of Ctena orbiculata]
>   PUB86139.1 phenol hydroxylase [gamma proteobacterium symbiont of Ctena
>   orbiculata] PUB79626.1 phenol hydroxylase [gamma proteobacterium
>   symbiont of Ctena orbiculata] PUB79624.1 phenol 2-monooxygenase [gamma
>   proteobacterium symbiont of Ctena orbiculata] PUB72973.1 phenol
>   2-monooxygenase [gamma proteobacterium symbiont of Ctena orbiculata]
>   PUB72971.1 phenol hydroxylase [gamma proteobacterium symbiont of Ctena
>   orbiculata] PWY90296.1 phenol monooxygenase [Aspergillus
>   sclerotioniger CBS 115572] PWY63616.1 phenol monooxygenase
>   [Aspergillus eucalypticola CBS 122712]

I have used this program

```
infile = open('out3.txt', 'r')
outfile = open('out5.txt', 'w')
for l in infile:
    outfile.write(l.split()[-1] + '\n')
infile.close()
outfile.close()
```

but it is not working

Comment: thank you reblochon sir i got the answer

Comment: Bit confused about your data.  Could you clarify where the line breaks are?

Comment: line breaks after bracket completion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a regular expression solution which works and retains the `[ ]`. 
The regular expression:  `r'(\[.+\])'`.

The leading `r` indicate a *raw string*, which prevents python interpolating the `\\` characters.

The outer parentheses `( )` are a *capturing group*, and will capture into a tuple returned by `m.groups()`.

The `[` have to be "escaped" because they are a regular expression meta-character.

The `.+` indicates *one or more* (`+`) of any character (`.`)

EDIT:  this version uses an `OrderedDict` to remove duplicates and retain order (which a `set` would not):

```
import re
from collections import OrderedDict
uniq = OrderedDict()

with open('gash.txt') as inf:
    for line in inf:
       m = re.search(r'(\[.+\])', line)
       if m:
           uniq[m.groups()[0]] = None

with open('out5.txt', 'w') as outf:
    print("\n".join(uniq.keys()), file=outf)
```

Gives in out5.txt:

```
[Aspergillus aculeatinus CBS 121060]
[gamma proteobacterium symbiont of Ctena orbiculata]
[Aspergillus vadensis CBS 113365]
[Aspergillus neoniger CBS 115656]
[Aspergillus sclerotioniger CBS 115572]
[Aspergillus eucalypticola CBS 122712]
```

Comment: I want only single line of data in bracket since it is giving duplicate data of bracket also for that what will be program

Comment: You don't want duplicates?  Why didn't you say that in your question?  Does the order matter?

Comment: yes i dont want duplicates yes order matters

Comment: @Hlokhande: please specify your exact requirement in future, and state how the code you tried was supposed to meet these requirements.  This is not a program writing service.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use regex in your program.
Regex are extremely useful for extracting text. 
Ex:

```
   import re

   s = "alphaCustomer bla bla bla [dataFindMe] bla bla bla"
   m = re.search(r"\[(\.+)\]", s)
   print m.group(1)
```

Output

```
   dataFindMe
```

Comment: Your pattern does not work with this data.  `\w` does not include whitespace.

Answer (score 0):

This should do exactly what you want:

```
infile = open('out3.txt', 'r')
outfile = open('out5.txt', 'w')

for line in infile:
    line = (line[line.find('[') + 1:])[:-2] + "\n"
    outfile.write(line)


infile.close()
outfile.close()
```

**out3.txt**

```
RAH71880.1 phenol monooxygenase [Aspergillus aculeatinus CBS 121060]
PVV21043.1 phenol 2-monooxygenase [gamma proteobacterium symbiont of Ctena orbiculata]
PVV21041.1 phenol hydroxylase [gamma proteobacterium symbiont of Ctena orbiculata]
PYH66749.1 phenol monooxygenase [Aspergillus vadensis CBS 113365]
PYH31415.1 phenol monooxygenase [Aspergillus neoniger CBS 115656]
PUB86175.1 phenol 2-monooxygenase [gamma proteobacterium symbiont of Ctena orbiculata]
PUB86141.1 phenol 2-monooxygenase [gamma proteobacterium symbiont of Ctena orbiculata]
PUB86139.1 phenol hydroxylase [gamma proteobacterium symbiont of Ctena orbiculata]
PUB79626.1 phenol hydroxylase [gamma proteobacterium symbiont of Ctena orbiculata]
PUB79624.1 phenol 2-monooxygenase [gamma proteobacterium symbiont of Ctena orbiculata]
PUB72973.1 phenol 2-monooxygenase [gamma proteobacterium symbiont of Ctena orbiculata]
PUB72971.1 phenol hydroxylase [gamma proteobacterium symbiont of Ctena orbiculata]
PWY90296.1 phenol monooxygenase [Aspergillus sclerotioniger CBS 115572]
PWY63616.1 phenol monooxygenase [Aspergillus eucalypticola CBS 122712]
```

**out5.txt**

```
Aspergillus aculeatinus CBS 121060
gamma proteobacterium symbiont of Ctena orbiculata
gamma proteobacterium symbiont of Ctena orbiculata
Aspergillus vadensis CBS 113365
Aspergillus neoniger CBS 115656
gamma proteobacterium symbiont of Ctena orbiculata
gamma proteobacterium symbiont of Ctena orbiculata
gamma proteobacterium symbiont of Ctena orbiculata
gamma proteobacterium symbiont of Ctena orbiculata
gamma proteobacterium symbiont of Ctena orbiculata
gamma proteobacterium symbiont of Ctena orbiculata
gamma proteobacterium symbiont of Ctena orbiculata
Aspergillus sclerotioniger CBS 115572
Aspergillus eucalypticola CBS 122712
```

---

**EDIT**

If you want print out just the unique lines, you could update the source code like this:

```
infile = open('out3.txt', 'r')
outfile = open('out5.txt', 'w')
unique = []

for line in infile:
    line = (line[line.find('[') + 1:])[:-2] + "\n"

    if line not in unique:
        unique.append(line)
        outfile.write(line)


infile.close()
outfile.close()
```

Then you will get output (out5.txt) like this:

```
Aspergillus aculeatinus CBS 121060
gamma proteobacterium symbiont of Ctena orbiculata
Aspergillus vadensis CBS 113365
Aspergillus neoniger CBS 115656
Aspergillus sclerotioniger CBS 115572
Aspergillus eucalypticola CBS 122712
```

Comment: And i also want to remove the duplicate data of bracket because it is containing same data in brackets then what will be program

Comment: @Hlokhande Then you can just save each unique data line in a list and then write it to the ouput file just when it's not yet in the given list.

Comment: but what will be program for that

Comment: I tried but not giving result

Comment: @Hlokhande can you provide more info? Show the code you tried?

Comment: infile = open('out3.txt', 'r')
outfile = open('out5.txt', 'w')

for line in infile:
    line = (line[line.find('[') + 1:])[:-2] + "\n"
    outfile.write(line)


infile.close()
outfile.close() this code i have used

Comment: @Hlokhande I've updated my answer, check it out.